# What's the term for a rotatable plumbing pipe "union" in the UK?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, uk

I've been searching for a specific plumbing fitting for UK BSPP threaded pipes / devices but I don't know what to call it. I'm not looking for a specific product recommendation, just the terminology.

---

In the USA I think the correct term for this device would be a "union" - like this example (having female NPT threads):

[image] [image]

The specific feature I'm looking for is the ability to **rotate** the two mating sides to any orientation (axially) but still end up with a rigid joint when you bring them together. To that end, in the above example each half of the union screws onto a pipe and then the two halves are themselves screwed together, sealing with an o-ring.

(Just to be really clear - [here's a video](https://youtu.be/_m2xg5e6RpE?t=13))

I don't necessarily need an identical device in BSPP, I just need something that can rotate in an equivalent way. But I don't know what to call it?

---

I have seen a few items using the term "union", such as the example below, but this is just a single solid piece (I'd call it a pipe nipple in the US):

[image]

There is also such a thing as a "bulkhead union" but that also is not equivalent to a US "union".

---

I have a feeling that this fitting must exist but without knowing what to call it I haven't been able to find one. I've tried coupling, coupler, etc.

In case you're wondering, US and UK pipe threads are totally incompatible so I can't use a local part.

(In particular I actually need one which is male-to-male, but I figured I should understand the basic terminology first!)

Comment: Are UK threaded pipes tapered like the US or are they parallel? In the countries that use parallel threads I gather that plumber's hemp fiber is use in addition to pipe joint compound.

Comment: @JimStewart there are both types. BSPP is parallel threads which use an O-ring. There's another variant (can't think of the name) is akin to NPT.

Comment: Just a comment that those pipe unions do not fit up by "sealing with an o-ring", there is no o-ring; the tapered machined internal sealing surfaces mate to each other to accomplish the seal. PVC unions do use an o-ring though...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I was referring to how the two halves mate with each other. The example in the photo is a tapered NPT but unions are available for various other pipe end types (PVC for example)

Comment: Yes, where the two halves mate with each other there is no o-ring. This is not about the tapered thread.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I see what you mean; the only ones I have seen did have an O ring but it makes sense there could be other types that seal in other ways too... thanks